# SVG path co-ordinates different from circle

Tags: svg

Must be something very trivial, but I'm unable to figure out why the line is not being drawn between the two points (represented by circles).

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="-10 -10 80 90"
     width="400" height="400" version="1.1">
  <path d="M 0 31.5 V 0,72" fill="none" id="bust" stroke="black"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="31.5" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="72" r="5"/>
</svg>
```

[Output in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrjNs.png)

Comment: Please use the L command instead of the V command: `d="M 0 31.5 L0,72"` When you use the V command it will draw first a vertical line to y=0 and next another vertical line to y=72

Comment: After V you really want one value i.e V 72

Answer (score 0):

As [Robert Longson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901265/svg-path-co-ordinates-different-from-circle/72906709#comment128763563_72901265), I only need single value after V.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="-10 -10 80 90"
     width="400" height="400" version="1.1">
  <path d="M 0 31.5 V 72" fill="none" id="bust" stroke="black"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="31.5" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="72" r="5"/>
</svg>
```